# How to make a geom_line with 3 different parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

So I have a data set that sorts DJs by Rank, the year they received that rank, and the name of the DJ that received the previously mention information on a horizontal access in Excel.

When I plot the data I'm currently working with it ends up displaying a line chart with the a vertical line from 1 to 5 for each year and I'm not sure what to do from here.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

DJMAG <- DJMAG_MOdified

Top <-data.frame(DJMAG$Year, DJMAG$Rank , DJMAG$DJ)

names(Top) <- c("Year","Rank","DJ")

ggplot(Top, aes(Top$Year)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = as.numeric(Top$Rank), color = "Hardwell")) + xlab("2004 to 2018") + ylab("Rank")
```

There are no error messages but What I'm trying to show with this data is how (X = Year) DJs with their own line plot increased or decreased in ranking from 2004 to 2017 and the rankings of the top 5, 1-5 on the Y-axis with an inverted y-axis.

Comment: Could you provide example data please, and do you mean a line plot where x = year, y = rank, and there is a line per DJ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was going for and then I would figure out how to color code each line to differentiate them.

Column 1 has Year with 2004 - 2017, 2004 - 2017, etc. listed 100 times , Column 2 has Rank with 1 listed 17 times for each respective year then 2 listed 17 times and so on
Column 3 has DJs with each respective DJ associated with that data listed by name

Answer (score 0):

So I took the liberty of coming up with some example data.

```
DJMAG_MOdified <- data.frame(Year=rep(2004:2018,3),
                    Rank=runif(45,0,1),
                    DJ=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=15),
                    Other=runif(45,0,1))
```

I purposefully added the `Other` column, so we still subset it as you have done.
Instead of your method which was:

```
Top <-data.frame(DJMAG$Year, DJMAG$Rank , DJMAG$DJ)
names(Top) <- c("Year","Rank","DJ")
```

It would be preferable to have it in one line where you dont need to change column names as follows:

```
Top <- DJMAG_MOdified[,c("Year","Rank","DJ")]
```

As for the plot, I am thinking maybe this is what you are looking for, where each DJ is represented by a different coloured line?

```
ggplot(Top, aes(x=Year,y=as.numeric(Rank))) + 
    geom_line(aes(col = DJ)) + 
    xlab("2004 to 2018") + 
    ylab("Rank")
```

I didnt understand where the `color = "Hardwell"` part of your code came from...

Comment: Ok I will try this out.  Ya the color = "Hardwell" was just a placeholder to label the line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  It worked the way I hoped it would, but if I wanted to invert the numbers to have 1 at the top  on the y - axis and 5 at the bottom how would I do that?

Comment: add `scale_y_reverse()`

Comment: ...in full, I'd go for: `ggplot(data = Top) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = year, y = rank, color = DJ)) + 
  scale_y_reverse()`

Comment: @rg255 if you want to edit the answer I will accept any changes. Although I think this should be added to the question if it is going to appear in an answer